# Wordpress links https overwrite issue

Tags: links, https

We're running WP woocommerce website, we got there problem with generating links.

Steam api is generating link in this format:
`steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198030116216A15860401386D2594883032411162261`
but wordpress is changing link into this:
`https://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198030116216A15860401386D16457881814965865661`
Its removing "Steam" and replacing with HTTPS.
Does anyone know where is problem? We're using Cloudflare and I tried disable feature "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites".

Thank you a lot for helpful replies. :)

Comment: I'd guess the code that's doing this is using [set_url_scheme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_url_scheme). So I'd start by editing that function in a dev environment (wp-includes/link-template.php) to throw an error if the input url starts with 'steam://', so that you can track down the code that's triggering this. Hopefully that'll point you in the right direction. Worst case there's also a filter [set_url_scheme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/set_url_scheme/) that you could use to check the original url and put 'steam://' back, but hopefully a better way